# Rails: Add params in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need 2 params to controll the view. Something like `http://localhost:3000/products?display=table&range=month`

[image]

So user can select `view by month/week`, or `display by thumbnail/table`

How can I do something like `link_to current_url, range: 'month'`, so the generated link based on current params? So it can append `&range=month` to `http://localhost:3000/products?display=thumbnail`.

I may not be quite clear in this description, so if you have any problem, just ask and I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one app I added to Application helper followin method

```
def repeat_current_params
   params.except(:controller, :action)
end
```

Then in view you might call
`link_to 'Name', repeat_current_params.merge(additional_param_key: 'its_value')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters like this `<%= link_to "Html text", <x>_path({param: value, param2, value2}) %>` Or to link to the current page, `<%= link_to "Html text", {param1: value1, param2: value2} %>`

Comment: No, the problem is to append a param to another. Not passing 2 params at the same time.

Comment: Ah I see, then it looks like what djaszczurowski suggested is more what you need.

Comment: Unless you mean some way to add parameters after the view has been rendered?

Comment: Ah...not, but djaszczurowski 's answer is great. Works under my circumstance.